# Unable to resolve field in Java when storing values from JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, actionevent

I'm having a trouble storing a value by using an `ActionListener` with a `JButton`. I'm fairly new to Java and not 100% confident in class and subclass way of programming.

```
import java.ActionEvent;
import javaActionListener;
import javax.swing JButton;
import javax.swing JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Trial extends JPanel implements Action Listener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Trial() {
        setFrame();
    }

    public void setFrame(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Trial");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Trial();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = field.getText();
        System.out.prinln("Button is pressed");
    }
}
```

field is undefined inside `actionPerformed`, why is this so? I played around with the ActionEvent, and it seems I can't pass in any variable outside of the `actionPerformed` function. So how do I go about doing this? Do I need to move `setFrame()` to its own class?

Comment: Why does `Trial` extend `JPanel`?  It seem completely unnecessary for it to do that.

Comment: the code is just a snippet of the original code. I just took the necessary code lines for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is down to the scope of the variable field.

In java the scope of a variable is set by the code block it is defined in. Your JTextField field, is declared within the setFrame method, this means the variable is only visible within the setFrame method.

If you want to make the field variable visible within the entire class so that you can access it in your actionPerformed method you can make it an instance variable.

```
public class Trial extends JPanel implements Action Listener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField field;    //Move your declaration to class level, making it an instance variable.

    public Trial() {
        setFrame();
    }

    public void setFrame(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Trial");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        field = new JTextField(10);    //Remove the declaration of the variable and just initialize it here.
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Trial();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = field.getText();   //Now you can access field within any method in the class.
        System.out.prinln("Button is pressed");
    }
}
```

Hopefully the above code explains it enough, any questions please comment and I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Your setFrame() method creates and initializes the field, but another method does not have a way to access that certain object with its certain properties.

Try this:

```
    public class Trial extends JPanel implements Action Listener {

    JTextField field;

    ..// omitted 

    public void setFrame()
    {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Trial");
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       field = new JTextField(10);

     .. //omitted
```

When having declared the -certain- object outside of any method, it would mean any method could access this -certain- object and modify (or retrieve) properties / methods from.